# Most suitable Machine Learning algorithm for this problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I have a dataset and i want to decide on which ML algorithm to apply to my given problem.

Customers are to fill out an assessment questionnaire of 50 questions. Examples of the questions are, what is your job, previous job history, how much do you earn, have you been rejected for a loan etc, and the end goal is to decide whether they should be rejected or not.

I have circa 500 entries for my algorithm to learn from and have pre-processed my dataset and converted the inputs into a numpy array and wondering what would be the best algorithm to use? Should i use a classification algorithm or a neural network in tensorflow and if the latter, what would be the layers I should use?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

How about beginning with `xgboost` or `random forest`? - So plain "old" ML?
The advantage would be that you could visualize the decision tree of the model once trained.

If using a NN in tensorflow (or even easier: keras with tensorflow backend), you could go with a MLP (multi layer perceptron), since the questions answers have fixed position in the input. You don't need many layers.

Important is that you normalize your input data columnwise, so that the input numbers are not much bigger/smaller than +1/-1, respectively. Introductory books often miss this point, though important.

Since your target labeling is "accept" or "reject", binary classifier will do it (also in the machine learning approach). (You use 0 and 1 as labels).

For NN, you don't need for such kind of classification that many layers or neurons. Try the smallest network first. let's say 10 neurons in first layer, then 7 neurons in the next layer (probably even less) and then 1 output neuron for the binary decision.

With Keras this would be:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

def create_mlp(n_input = 500): # number of columns of input data 500 here
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=n_input, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')) # init = kernel_initializer
    model.add(Dense(7, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['acc'])
    return model

model = create_mlp(500) # this will generate the correct NN compiled.
```

Your data frame (or Numpy input array must have as rows the samples,
the columns are for each answer for a question 1 column.
the answers you have to encode in a numeric form. Numbers should be small - the best between -1 and 1. NNs don't like big numbers. Thus column-wise normalization can help.)

That's it. I learned all this stuff last year. Good luck for learning. It will be tons of fun!

Comment: 500 could be enough. It he train-test splits with ratio `.1` (then his train dataset is 450 samples). If the decision underlies a simple rule, it will be more than enough!

Comment: try nn on iris dataset, and what would perform better: nn, or stacked ensemble with a linear model and rf on first level and rf as a second level. for a nn to perform well you either need data with tens of thousands data or a very specific 2d data (images) or sequences (timeseries data). And even in the latter cases you need tens of thousands data points for nn to perform well.

Comment: is input_dim the length of my dataset of the length of the input array?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Do you use NN in real life? I do. I would say it strictly depends on data. If the data is very clearly distinguishable, few 3 figure number of samples will be enough. maybe even hundred. Iris dataset has only 50 datasets. Yet you can train small NNs on it. iris dataset however has some samples by intention not easily distinguishable. So with best models you will get 98%.

Comment: @Jay length of input array. Study one of the thousands of beginner tutorials for MLP NN in keras.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim but i didn't say the len of the input array will be 500. I mean that i have 500 samples in my dataset.

Comment: @Jay well then change the number to what you need.